# How to catch exceptions from ApolloClient watch method?

Tags: kotlin, apollo-client, apollo-android, apollo-kotlin

This code - manual query execution without watch - throws an exception as I expect it (due to an intentionally wrong server url not shown here):

```
try {
    val response = apolloClient.query(MyQuery()).execute()
} catch (e: Exception) {
    Timber.e("exception from manual execution")
    Timber.e(e)
}
```

However, if instead I use watch (and intentionally the same wrong server url) like in the following code, I get no exception:

```
try {
    apolloClient.query(MyQuery())
        .watch() // flow
        .collect { response ->
            Timber.i("apollo watch collect called")
        }
} catch (e: Exception) {
    Timber.e("exception from watch execution")
    Timber.e(e)
}
```

Where is my error? Why don't I get an exception in the second case? How to catch errors when using watch?

Comment: By default watch method will not throw an exception will return an error object as part of the query result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
apolloClient.query(MyQuery())
        .watch( fetchThrows = true, refetchThrows = true) // need this
        .catch{t->}//catch here
        .collect { response ->
            Timber.i("apollo watch collect called")
        }
```

Comment: thank you, that worked fine and looks the most intuitive to me :-) it needs to be combined with `.watch( fetchThrows = true, refetchThrows = true)` though.

Answer (score 0):

use a callback on the `ApolloQueryWatcher` instance. Here is an example from [GitHub](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-kotlin/issues/2096#issue-585861048)

Also use `.responseFetcher(ApolloResponseFetchers.CACHE_ONLY)` with any `enqueueAndWatch` calls to make sure that watchers won't perform any network requests when the cache is updated and prevent [Infinite loops](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-kotlin/issues/2226)

Comment: You Github example seems to be for an older version of Apollo Kotlin

Answer (score 0):

The `collect` function starts the flow and consumes the emitted values, but it does not throw any exceptions.

Use the `onCompletion` operator to handle any errors that occur during the execution of the flow.

```
apolloClient.query(MyQuery())
    .watch()
    .onCompletion { throwable ->
        if (throwable != null) {
            Timber.e("error from watch execution")
            Timber.e(throwable)
        }
    }
    .collect { response ->
        Timber.i("apollo watch collect called")
    }
```

A slight improvement: if the emitted values are being ignored it is possible to just use
`.launchIn(scope)` instead of `.collect { response -> ...`

Comment: thank you for your reply. I went with the `catch` way though as it seems more intuitive to me.